# Xamarin - Adding icons to drawer menu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, icons, navigation-drawer

I'm thinking of adding icons to my drawer menu items, however I can't think of a way to do it. This is how the drawer looks:
[image]
How can I add icons on the left side of the text like this:
[image]

Code:

```
            currentFragment = dashboard;
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            leftDataSet = new List<string>();
            leftDataSet.Add(GetString(Resource.String.dashboard_title));
            leftDataSet.Add(GetString(Resource.String.smoke_sensor_title));
            leftDataSet.Add(GetString(Resource.String.motion_sensor_title));
            leftDataSet.Add(GetString(Resource.String.door_sensor_title));
            leftDataSet.Add(GetString(Resource.String.temperature_sensor_title));
            leftDataSet.Add(GetString(Resource.String.gallery_title));
            leftAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, leftDataSet);
            leftDrawer.Adapter = leftAdapter;

            //
            //  Change to the appropriate fragment view when the user clicks on an item from the left drawer
            //
            leftDrawer.ItemClick += (sender, args) => {
                SelectItem(args.Position);
            };

            drawerToggle = new MenuDrawer(
                this, drawerLayout, Resource.String.open_drawer, Resource.String.dashboard_title  //Closed Message (not used but required to declare)
            );

            drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            drawerToggle.SyncState();
        }

        private void SelectItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ShowFragment(dashboard);
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.dashboard_title);
                break;
            case 1:
                ShowFragment(smokeSensor);
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.smoke_sensor_title);
                break;
            case 2:
                ShowFragment(motionSensor);
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.motion_sensor_title);
                break;
            case 3:
                ShowFragment(doorSensor);
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.door_sensor_title);
                break;
            case 4:
                ShowFragment(temperatureSensor);
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.temperature_sensor_title);
                break;
            case 5:
                ShowFragment(gallery);
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.gallery_title);
                break;
            default:
                ShowFragment(currentFragment);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I created an overridden View and it works, however I'm still not certain how to add icons:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;

namespace Homecheck.Adapters {
    public class CustomListView : BaseAdapter<string> {

        //
        // This adapter overrides the basic Android ListView design with a custom one.
        // The custom layout can display pictures along with the text, and the design can be changed very easilly using xml.
        //
        private List<string> items;
        private Context context;

        public CustomListView(Context context, List<string> items) {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        //
        //  Counts how many items are there in the ListView (Dashboard, Smoke Sensor, Motion sensor etc.)
        //  They reside in values*/Strings.xml (* depends on the language)
        //
        public override int Count {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public override string this[int position] {
            get { return this.items[position]; }
        }

        //
        // Populates each row in the ViewList with an image and a text.
        //
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null) {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(this.context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MenuDrawer, null, false);
            }

            TextView text = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);
            text.Text = this.items[position];
            ImageView icon = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);
//          ????

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an outdated version of the navigation drawer. That one hasn't got support for icons out of the box. I would recommend looking the example of James: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer/tree/master/Design%20Support%20Library%20(Material)/AppCompat%20v14%2B

In that one you are able to define your menu including icons like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="Browse" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_friends"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
        android:title="Friends" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
        android:title="Profile" />
</group>

<item android:title="Sub items">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Sub item 1" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Sub item 2" />
    </menu>
</item>
```